# If the silicon wafers from which the processors are made are so sensitive that workers wear special suits how is delidding a processor possible?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, microprocessor, cooling

I saw many videos on YouTube in which people delid processors and then apply better liquids for cooling the processor. Example: *[i5 & i7 Haswell & Ivy Bridge - FULL Delid Tutorial - (Vice Method)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_rji1Nx5qM)*

However I also saw that people working in fabs are wearing special costumes, because the silicon wafers are extremely sensitive to all kinds of particles.

What actually happens when delidding a processor?

Comment: When one speck of dust gets onto a processor on manufacturing, it is runined. When one gets ont to a delidded processor, what happens?

Comment: The fabrication is indeed exquisitely sensitive to contamination. However, once the chip is finished, it is relatively insensitive. Even more important, the surface of the chip exposed during delidding is the back side of the chip, where there is nothing which can affect operation. The active side, where all the circuits are, is buried in the package and not affected.

Comment: Note that PC processors - like the Athlon XP -  used to be sold without a lid for years. Yes, a bare die on a supporting PCB.

Comment: @TurboJ http://techreport.com/r.x/northwood-vs-2000/axp2k.jpg

Comment: Why use old chips as an example? Laptop CPUs are still bare dies. Also GPUs and mainboard chipsets, and even some SSD controllers.......

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Wafers are extremely sensitive during manufacture, because if any dust or dirt particle settles on it **between** any process steps, then the following process steps will fail on the contaminated spot.

Once manufacture is finished, and the chip receives its last layer, dust will no longer bother it.

I would venture a guess that desktop CPUs which have thermal spreading lids on them will receive a proper surface treatment for application of the chosen thermal paste.

Comment: Also note that those processors have the silicon substrate facing up, not the metallization layer.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, depends on the package. Historically lots of CPUs were made with the patterned side of the chip facing up.

Comment: @ThePhoton: indeed, however in the context of the OP it seems to refer to contemporary x86_64 processors and the "delidding" by removing the heatspreader that is mounted/glued/soldered directly onto the silicon.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that. I remember now, the old Athlons, which had the silicon back side exposed, and you'd just stick the heat sink on it. Could crack the die if careless. http://cdn.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K7/L_AMD-AXDA1800DLT3C.jpg

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I don't see anywhere in the question that mentions a specific processor. But I didn't click through to the video.

Comment: @ThePhoton: already the mention of "many videos on youtube" about "cooling the processor" should tell you that its about mainstream desktop computers ;)

Comment: Compary an already printed on piece of paper getting very dusty vs trying to print something on very dusty paper!

Answer (score 18):

Something not mentioned by the other answers is that it's not only the chip itself that's so sensitive to dust. It's also the lithography plates used to print the resist layers for each stage of the process.

[image]

Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photomask)

Incredibly advanced optics are used to project light through these essentially "film negatives" onto the resist layer on the wafer. These negatives are several times larger than the actual features to help reduce the effect of error in the plate, but feature size is only around 4-5x larger. The UV light is shown through them, and focused down to the appropriate dimensions to expose the resist at the appropriate resolution. With current process technology reaching down to 10nm, these litho plates have to be "perfect" because they rely on diffraction techniques to print features many times smaller than the wavelength of light used. If a spec of dust were to get on one of these plate, it would ruin every chip subsequently printed with that area of the litho plate.

Comment: "slightly smaller" herein meaning 20x as (barring EUV) a wavelength of ~193nm is used, but anyway :)

Comment: @sam, It was in a class I took several years ago... I didn't bother to look up the exact value :P

Comment: Not sure if this is true. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_device_fabrication#History), cleanrooms filter out particles, which could **come to rest on the wafers** and contribute to defects. If the features on the plates are 100 times larger than on the chip, it seems logical that plates can survive contamination by particles 100 times larger than wafers.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev 100x was a number I pulled out of my ass... someone should have called me on it earlier. I did some additional reading, and fixed my statements. To get the entire story on how cutting edge lithography works, it would take a PHD dissertation, which is beyond the scope of this post.

Answer (score 17):

A passivation layer is the final step, excluding the atmosphere. This layer is formed by exposing the wafer to high temperature oxygen (low growth rate) or steam (high growth rate). Result is silicon-dioxide, 1,000s of Angstroms thick.

The edges of the integrated circuit are usually protected against ionic intrusion, with a "seal ring" where the metals and implants are tapered down to pure silicon substrate. But be careful; the seal-ring is a conductive path along the edge of the IC, thus allows *interference* to be transmitted along the edge of the IC.

For successful systems-on-chip, you'll need to evaluate break-the-sealring early on in your silicon prototyping, so you know the degradation of isolation, the damage to noise-floor, caused by deterministic noise being overtly conducted into the sensitive regions of the IC. If the sealring injects 2milliVolts of trash, on every clock edge, can you expect to achieve 100 nanoVolt performance? Oh, right, averaging overcomes all evils.

EDIT Delidding of some precision matched integrated circuits will alter the mechanical stresses imposed on the silicon, and the numerous transistors, resistors, capacitors thereon; changes in stresses alter the minute distortions of the silicon along crystal axes and alter the piezoelectric responses, which permanently alters underlying electric error sources in otherwise matched structures. To avoid this error, some manufacturers use enhanced features (extra transistors, extra layers of doping, etc) to add trim-while-using behaviors; in this, upon every power-up event the integrated circuit automatically runs through a calibration sequence.

Answer (score 13):

As @WhatRoughBeast correctly noted in the comment, the CPU die placed on the PCB doesn't expose any fine structures, which are located on the other side of the die. There are even low-cost CPUs which are sold without the lid, like this one:

[image]

If you [look closer](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/80/Intel_Microprocessor_Celeron_900_AW80585900_SLGLQ_in_mPGA478MN_socket-3595.jpg), you'll see that the CPU survived not only dust and thermal paste, but also a few scratches and a cracked corner, which clearly means there's nothing important on this side of the die.

Comment: Also, hand-bonding "bare die" semiconductor components under clean but by no means cleanroom conditions, eg in making custom hybrid circuits or modules, is not uncommon practice.

Answer (score 2):

The key here, as WhatRoughBeast and PlasmaHH have said, is the lack of exposure of sensitive parts of the CPU die. Only the bottom plane seems to be exposed (a characteristic typical of flip-chip designs).

One could be inclined to think that if the chip is not flipped but a passivation layer is present, the chip would be protected enough. Unfortunately, that would only save the chip from particles but not from any other accidental damage happening due to the lid being hammered away, like broken wire bondings and crushed 3D structures (air bridges).

Also, a passivation layer isn't always present  because it can severely impair a foundry process at high frequencies - this happens often with MMICs (monolithic microwave integrated circuits). I wouldn't rely on it if I didn't know positively that it's there.

In this case, I see far more dangers from the delidding process itself than from the chip being exposed in a non-clean environment after being delidded.